Archive iOS Flutter: Module 'flutter_keyboard_visibility' not found
I am trying to release my app on iOS, when building for iOS even with the --release flag, everything works well. The app runs perfectly fine on the simulator.
When I go on Xcode and archive the app, I get the "Module 'flutter_keyboard_visibility' not found" error. I don't have this dependency in my pubspec.yaml file so it's from another packet. I have tried even adding it to the pubspec file and getting the packages again. I even tried bumping up the minimum release version, as one post said here on Stack Overflow. I cannot get my app to be built.

Please consider adding a relevant piece of code, or maybe some configuration information. What does "archiving the app" look like?
